# DMing a specific user with ID

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I went through other questions trying to find the answer to this and came to the following code:

```js
let Prayer = message.member.user.tag;
bot.users.cache.get("my_id").send("My goddess, " + Prayer + " has sent you a prayer!");
```

However, I get this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined
```

I don't know why it says this since it works for others as well. Can someone help me?

Edit:

New code is now

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const bot = new Discord.Client();
let Prayer = message.member.user.tag;
async function SendingPray() {
      message.reply("Test3");
      const Yuuki = await bot.users.fetch('715912580127785060');
      message.reply("Test4");
      console.log(Yuuki);
      message.reply("Test5");
      Yuuki.send("Testing");
      message.reply("Test6");
};
SendingPray();
message.reply("your pray has been sent. The goddess will read your pray and decide your fate!");
```

It gets as far as Test3 but after that Test 4 won't appear and Yuuki won't get logged.

Results:
Special thanks to @Karizma for solving this with me!

On the end of index.js must say

```
module.exports = bot;
```

While the pray.js (using command handler) has the following code:

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'pray',
    description: 'Pray to the goddess!',
    usage: '[command name]',
    execute(message, args){
        const Discord = require("discord.js");
        const { Client } = require('discord.js');
        const bot = require("path_to_index.js")
        const token = require("path_to_your_token");
        bot.login(token.login_token);
        //token_login is how I stored my token to login the bot
        let Prayer = message.member.user.tag;
            async function SendingPray() {
                const Yuuki = await bot.users.fetch('ID_wanted').catch(err => {
                    console.error(err);
                    //means the user id is invalid
                });
                Yuuki.send("My goddess, " + Prayer + " has sent you a pray!").catch(console.error);
            };
            SendingPray();
        message.reply("your pray has been sent. The goddess will read your pray and decide your fate!");
    }
}
```

The problem was that the ID couldn't be fetched while the bot hasn't been redefined through the new file by adding code in 7-9, directing back to index.js

Comment: Is this code inside a `message` handler or it's just like this in a file? Because if it's not inside a `message` event handler then the `message` variable is undefined, you should get an unhandled promise rejection

Comment: Its in a message handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are fetching a user you have to call `.catch` on the method incase it fails

```js
async function SendingPray() {
      message.reply("Test3");
      const Yuuki = await bot.users.fetch('715912580127785060').catch(err => {
          console.error(err);
          //means the user id is invalid
      });
      message.reply("Test4");
      console.log(Yuuki);
      message.reply("Test5");
      Yuuki.send("Testing");
      message.reply("Test6");
};
```

I have tested out the id on discord and it seems that it is invalid.

Comment: Update the post with the updated code, don't comment it

Comment: Interesting. My ID isn't right. But how? I right clicked myself and copied my ID. Would you add me on Discord so we can figure my ID out? Never had that issue before.

Comment: The error message is following:  `Request to use token, but token was unavailable to the client.`

Comment: Yea add me on discord so we can resolver it easier, Karizma#0007